# Eclipse Helios not loading/starting , taking time to launch

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-3.6

I am using Eclipse Helios. Last days I am facing problem that Eclipse Helios is taking very much time to launch. When I checked the Task manager, I found that the Memory usage linked to eclipse Helios is growing very slowly and at 31,132 K it stucks and then suddenly it catches a 62,000 K of space and eclipse get launched.
I found the same issue with my other system, So i realized it is something eclipse.
Can anybody suggest me the solution of the same or I need to format my system.

My System Configuration-
Windows XP , 4GB Ram , i5 Processor

**Adding more , as soon as I open the eclipse , immediatly the tray manager shows the eclipse program as Not Responding, then I need to wait for next 10 - 15 mins to get the eclipse launched.**

Comment: do you see the same with a new, blank workspace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be hitting an issue similar to [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=338176). Check your anti-virus software.

Comment: Thanks Prakash , will try the same as updated in the bug and then update.

Comment: Hi Prakash, as per the link suggested I made all the changes and even I removed my entire AV , but nothing changed with eclipse. Is there any other problem might raise this issue which you can address

Answer (score 0):

Probably its taking time as it is building the code before launching the application

Click on Windows-->Preferences

Now on the left handside tree Select "Run/Debug-->Launching"  and uncheck the "Build(if required) before launching" option

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Actually the trouble I am facing is with Memory assignment, so your solution is not justifying. But Thanks for input.